# How can i select a a tag and after pressing button i can go to specified href link

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

**The code of a href link that comes dynamically from database**

```
@foreach($doctor->tuesday as $tuesday)
<a class="timing" id="{{$tuesday->id}}" onclick="clicktime({{$tuesday->id}})" href="{{url('/')}}/fixschedule/{{$tuesday->id}}">
<span>{{date("g:i a",strtotime($tuesday->starttime))}}</span>
</a>
@endforeach
```

after select class name will be change to timing selected for blue highlight,

[i want to select an a element like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3njg9.png)

when i will press the button then the i want to redirect the specified link of a href
and i want to select only one element at a time

**code of button**

```
<div class="submit-section proceed-btn text-right">
<a href="#" onclick="submit()" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn">Proceed to Pay</a>
</div>
```

i used here code of jquery that only one element can change now i want to go only redirected link after submit pressed

```
<script>
    function clicktime(id)
    {
      $("a").removeClass("timing selected");
      $("a").toggleClass("timing");
      document.getElementById(id).className = "timing selected";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Most likely this is just a checkbox or radiobutton that's styled to look like a a button, and on select it sends you to a link.

Answer (score 0):

First, prevent the a tag from redirecting with preventDefault();

```
@foreach($doctor->tuesday as $tuesday)
<a class="timing" id="{{$tuesday->id}}" onclick="preventDefault();clicktime({{$tuesday->id}})" 
href="{{url('/')}}/fixschedule/{{$tuesday->id}}">
<span>{{date("g:i a",strtotime($tuesday->starttime))}}</span>
</a>
@endforeach
```

then set the url on code of button like

```
<script>
function clicktime(id)
{
  $("a").removeClass("timing selected");
  $("a").toggleClass("timing");
  document.getElementById(id).className = "timing selected";
  $(".submit-btn").attr('href',$("#"+id).attr('href');
}
</script>
```